# Setting up Windows Server 2019 to allow sending mail in Classic ASP/PHP

Tags: smtp, windows-server-2019

I'm working on migrating over to a new server and I'm trying to setup the server to allow PHP/Classic ASP to send emails from forms etc..

I followed these instructions and used the IP **127.0.0.1** where it asked.
https://phoenixnap.com/kb/windows-smtp-server

However, I can't get any mail to send via PHP nor classic ASP. On the bottom of the article, it mentions testing via telnet, after **MAIL FROM** I get 500 command unknown or something like that.

Any assistance is appreciated.

Thank You